# How to check if an object is at a coordinate

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an object with an x and y coordinate. These objects are placed randomly on a grid, not overlapping and also not necessarily integer coordinates. I want to check if there is an object at some location (a,b). I know I can cycle through all the objects and brute force check like this

```
for (object o : objectList) {
    if (o.x == a && o.y == b) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But if I have a lot of objects and I'm using this checking method often, it will not be fast enough. How can I make this more efficient?

Comment: You have these objects in a collection of sorts? Sort it based on the position.

Comment: There are lots of choices of data structures to do this, e.g. a [K-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree).

Comment: Why not keep your positions in a `Set<Point>`?

Comment: Is your object a Point or smth else?

Comment: @dehasi it's a class I made. I can't just use point because it uses non-integer values

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume `object` is a class you made, since otherwise `o.x` would be invalid. Anyway, there are a few ways to approach this, but the easiest way is probably through a 2-dimensional array.

Use `x` as one index, and `y` as another. Something like: `object[][] objsAt = new object[maxX][maxY]`. Then, to check an object at a certain coordinate, do `obj = objsAt[x][y]`.

You could also use more advanced techniques like [Maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), although I'm guessing you would have thought of them if you had already learned about those :)

Comment: See the problem is the coordinates are not necessarily integer. If they were integer, this wouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a class which represents a point. I suggest you implement `Comparable<>` interface. Then sort your points. And then check if there are two equal points following one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java, you can use HashSet<> to store your objects.
But you need to implement your own equals and hashCode methods on your class.
Time complexity of HashSet is only  O(1) for add() and contain().

For example,

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class DoublePoint {
    private double x,y;
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        long temp;
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(x);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        temp = Double.doubleToLongBits(y);
        result = prime * result + (int) (temp ^ (temp >>> 32));
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        DoublePoint other = (DoublePoint) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }



    public DoublePoint(double x, double y) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<DoublePoint> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(new DoublePoint(1.5, 2.5));
        System.out.println(set.contains(new DoublePoint(1.5, 2.5)));//return true
    }
}
```